# Android DSL documentation for gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For gradle there is a base set of documentation available for the dsl: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/

Maybe I'm just really blind, but I can't seem to find an equivalent set of detailed documentation for android. :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What you are looking for is here http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html

Comment: getting closer...but still not the same level of detail.

Comment: @CasualT What does DSL mean ?

Comment: domain specific language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interim solution:

```
def explainMe(it){
    println "Examining $it.name:"
    println "Meta:"
    println it.metaClass.metaMethods*.name.sort().unique()
    println "Methods:"
    println it.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
    println "Depends On:"
    println it.dependsOn.collect({it*.getName()})
    println "Properties:"
    println it.properties.entrySet()*.toString().sort().toString().replaceAll(", ","\n")
}
```

Comment: I know the question is closed, but have you tried [that one](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151483/android-dsl-documentation-for-gradle/21167414?noredirect=1#comment56138696_21151483

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html seems to be what you want?

In particular the downloadable javadoc zip with the 'plugin language reference'.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @KevinBrown I understand the guidelines, however the link is what was asked for. It is impossible to reproduce the entire documentation in an answer. It is also not possible to directly link an online browsable version of the documentation because, currently, it is only distributed as a zip archive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an "equivalent" documentation for the Android plugin. What is available is the [Android plugin docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).

Comment: lol, ya, that's more equivalent to this: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html.  I'm really surprised they don't have anything else, because you can't really learn/figure out the DSL very easily beyond the examples they have in the user guide.

Comment: I'm sure they would be happy to get your feedback.

Comment: At least for the pure-gradle stuff there are near-infinite amounts of documentation available. :D So I've been resorting to using tricks like this: http://groovy-almanac.org/list-the-methods-of-a-groovy-class/ to see what's available at different levels.

Comment: It is on my todo list to provide more feedback, but I'm also fairly certain that proper doc must be on their todo list as well.

Comment: Also.  This would seem to apply to their current docs:  http://goo.gl/0UaB3j :P